# Formatting C# code in text, like Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms

If you notice in this very editor that I am writing in right now, when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and then paste your code and save it, it will become formatted like it was in Visual Studio.

Now I want to do my own program using Windows Forms and I would like to view the snippets of codes I save and format it accordingly.

Comment: I am using [Scintilla.Net](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) as a syntax coloring text editor.

Comment: today it's much easier - with Roslyn: [1](http://dogschasingsquirrels.com/2014/07/19/formatting-c-with-roslyn/), [2](http://www.christophdebaene.com/blog/2011/10/26/roslyn-formatting-code/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my blog, I use [Manoli's C# formatter](http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/).

The source code of the formatter [is available](http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/CSharpFormat.zip).

Basically you collect all the keywords, compiler directives...etc. and use regular expressions to find them. Then the author wraps HTML tags around them to format the text.

You could follow the same approach and include your own formatting which is compatible with whichever Windows Forms control you want to use.

Comment: page not available, any other reference?

Comment: @KunjahamedP Source code is from the early 2000s, only copy I could find is here https://github.com/RickStrahl/CodePaste.NET