# Get list of C# Classes Names?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am implementing a syntax highlighter using C# windows forms, and would like to get a list of all names, I know that this should be done manually, adding keywords and names but i was wondering if there is a function in C# that could help me do this.

Comment: What are "_C# Classes Names_"? Can you provide an example, maybe with pseudo code to show what you need?

Comment: Like DataTable, ViewState, GridView, .............etc.

Comment: So you need to show the class' name in a syntax highlighter when the user enters the class' name?? What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: _"I am implementing a syntax highlighter using C# windows forms"_ Why don't you write a Visual Studio extension? It's a lot easier than building your own syntax highlighter.

Comment: Can you explain "CodeCaster", i am trying to do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892884/formating-c-sharp-code-in-text.

Comment: I think a syntax highlighter is based on the syntax: so instead of hardcoding class names, you might just want to know when to expect one, and highlight accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use the [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get the names of classes in a dll.

```
// Using Reflection to get information from an Assembly:
System.Reflection.Assembly o = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("mscorlib.dll");
var types = o.GetTypes();
```

Comment: Can you please give a simple example or a reference.

Comment: let me google that for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79693/getting-all-types-in-a-namespace-via-reflection - see Aku's great answer, +1 it!

Answer (score 4):

Use reflection.

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass)).GetTypes()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
  List<string> namespaceList = new List<string>();
  List<string> returnList = new List<string>();
  foreach (Type type in asm.GetTypes())
{
    if (type.Namespace == nameSpace)
        namespaceList.Add(type.Name);
}
    foreach (String className in namespaceList)
    returnList.Add(className);
    return returnList;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list for all assemblies in C#.NET using reflection.

Example :

```
Assembly mscorlib = typeof(string).Assembly;
foreach (Type type in mscorlib.GetTypes())
{
    Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
}
```