# Write text (C# code) in a text file with indentation

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-io, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting C# code in text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892884/formatting-c-sharp-code-in-text)

Revised Question:
I have an input text file which contains C# code. Code is not indented. I have read all the text and now want to write this text (code) back in to text file but with indentation.

So lets say if i have input.

```
void myFunction(string a)
{
a = "abc";
              for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
     a += "a";
   }
              }
```

Output should be (in text file.)

```
void myFunction(string a)
{
    a = "abc";
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        a += a";
    }
}
```

I am not talking about formatting code in Visual Studio. I am talking about writing this to a text file with indentation.

Comment: Seeing the answer, what exactly do you need ? do you want to format your code in visual studio or you want to write to a text file using C# code in a formatted manner ?

Comment: You could use this website as a helper: http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/

Comment: i want to write it in text file.

Answer (score 7):

You can just open the text file on VS and format it,
Choose Edit->Advanced->Format Document

[image]

Comment: I Think he wants to do this with code.

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses It depends on how you set the VS in the first time you upload it, I choose c#..

Comment: And keep in mind, that you can edit the templates somewhere in VS. That could be neccessary if you get the clue, that this format is not the very best.

Comment: oh no, you are getting it wrong. i am not talking about visual studio. I want to write in same format in text file.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a program to format your c# code you might find this useful:

[Formatting C# code in text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892884/formatting-c-sharp-code-in-text)

Comment: +1 for referring to a source code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply the formatting  of **all files** at once. Using the Macro defined in  the below blog

http://timwise.blogspot.in/2009/01/format-all-document-in-visual-studio.html